Calculating actual interest rate from LIBOR like quotes
While LIBOR is discontinued, however in many emerging countries LIBOR like quotes are still available and used for discounting. One such country is India.
The page https://www.fbil.org.in/#/home gives quotes for MIBOR (Mumbai fixing) daily quotes.
My question however exactly the value of interest is calculated from such quotes?
Let say O/N quote is 8%. Then for 100 borrowing exactly how much to pay as interest? is it 8%/365? or 8%/360? Then again, if there is weekend then what will be the actual value of interest? will it be 8% * 2/360?
Any insight or online Workout will be very helpful
